# how can i reset my facebook like button counter

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, reset

i want to reset my facebook like counter on my web sites.

This is 13 like  http://www.evgor.com.tr/asp/product/5083/Trend-Avangarde-Yatak-Odasi
This is 509 like http://www.evgor.com.tr/asp/product/5759/Ikons-Salon-Takimi

and i want to reset all products like counter. What can i do this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When creating the like button you have an option to specify for what URL the like will belong.

Appending a GET query string to that option (like `?v=1`, or whatever) will make facebook treat it as a completely different like set, and reset the like count to zero.